# Зачем нужен паттерн "итератор"?

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

На курсах C# регулярно говорят о паттерне "итератор". Зачем он вообще нужен если мы можем нужные элементы отправить в коллекцию и работать уже с ней? Зачем нужны пользовательские коллекции если можно использовать стандартные?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Итератор это "не пользовательские коллекции", а **инструмент обхода** этой коллекции и не только коллекции, а вообще всего, что можно последовательно перебрать по какому то алгоритму. Обход коллекции всего лишь частный случай.

Алгоритм перебора скрыт внутри итератора, что позволяет иметь отдельно сам объект данных и много итераторов с разными алгоритмами обхода (SRP)

То есть итератор - класс инкапсулирующий в себе какой алгоритм обхода данных со стандартизированным интерфейсом "перечислитель"

Answer (score 10):

Итератор абстрагирует от вас не только саму коллекцию, но и **состояние** её обхода. Например, для массива это текущий индекс, для структур, основанных на дереве, это текущий узел, и так далее. Без итераторов вам пришлось бы для каждой коллекции знать, как именно её обходить, и иметь доступ к её внутренним структурам (например, sorted set, основанный на дереве, обычно не выставляет свои узлы в публичный доступ).

---

Зачем нужны пользовательские коллекции? Очень просто: стандартные не всегда умеют то, что вам нужно. Например, если вы хотите смоделировать взаимно-однозначное соответствие (то есть типа `Dictionary`, но чтобы можно было также по значению быстро находить ключ), вам придётся писать свою коллекцию.